# connected graph from a file and weights

Tags: java

The problem Statement is: 
Write a java program that reads a connected graph from a file.The program should prompt the user to enter the name of the file, then two vertices and display the shortest path between the two vertices.
The contents of the file are:

6
0, 1, 100 | 0, 2, 3
1, 3, 20
2, 3, 40 | 2, 4, 2
3, 4, 5 | 3, 5, 5
4, 5, 9 |

where 1st line = no. of vertices
Each subsequent line describes the edges in the form of u1, v1, w1 | u2, v2, w2 |.....
(Hint: Read the first line to get the number of vertices. Read each subsequent line into a string s and use s.split("[\|]") to extract the triplets. For each triplet, triplet.split("[,]") to extract vertices and weight.

My problem is that I am not able to extract vertices and weight from each triplet.

Thanks!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class testing 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a file name: ");
    File file = new File(input.nextLine());

    if (!file.exists())
    {
        System.out.println("File does not exist");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    System.out.print("Enter two vertices (integer indexes): ");
    int vertex1 = input.nextInt();
    int vertex2 = input.nextInt();

    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(file);
    // Read the number of vertices
    String s = inFile.nextLine();
    int numberOfVertices = Integer.parseInt(s);
    System.out.println("The number of vertices is " + numberOfVertices);

    List<WeightedEdge> list = new ArrayList<WeightedEdge>();

    while (inFile.hasNext())
    {
        s = inFile.nextLine();
        String[] triplet = s.split("[\\|]");
        for (String i : triplet)
            String[] tokens = triplet.split("[,]"); 

        int u = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0].trim());
        int v = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1].trim());
        int w = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2].trim());

    }

}
```

}

Comment: `Set<Vertex> vertices = new HashSet<>();` - then in the while loop: `vertices.add(new Vertex(u)); vertices.add(new Vertex(v));`. Something like that?

Comment: Are you asking your homework in stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a file name: ");
    File file = new File(input.nextLine());

    if (!file.exists())
    {
        System.out.println("File does not exist");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    System.out.print("Enter two vertices (integer indexes): ");
    int vertex1 = input.nextInt();
    int vertex2 = input.nextInt();

    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(file);
    // Read the number of vertices
    String s = inFile.nextLine();
    int numberOfVertices = Integer.parseInt(s);
    System.out.println("The number of vertices is " + numberOfVertices);

    List<WeightedEdge> list = new ArrayList<WeightedEdge>();

    while (inFile.hasNext())
    {
        String [] tokens = null;
        s = inFile.nextLine();
        String[] triplet = s.split("[\\|]");
            //this will always overwrite tokens
            //And triplet has 4 positions (0,1,2,3) so you cant just have int u,v and w
            /*
        for (String i : triplet){
            tokens = i.split("[,]"); 
        }
            */

        int u = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0].trim());
        int v = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1].trim());
        int w = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2].trim());

    }
}
```

You can't split an array lol. Other thing your `List<WeightedEdge> list = new ArrayList<WeightedEdge>();` is nowhere to be found and your `vertex1` and `vertex2` aren't used you knew that didn't you ?